# Integrating Google Places API without using Google Maps API?

Tags: ios, swift, google-places-api, google-places

I'm attempting to build my first app. I have a `UITextField` that I want to have access to the Google Places API to search restaurants nearby. I do not need to view these locations on a map, I just need to return search results that the user can tap to see more detail about the location. What are the steps to integrating the Google Places API after I've installed `pod GooglePlaces`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, if you want to use just a textfield which return establishments around you as a list you can do it like this using google places auto complete.

Follow those steps,

1) install google places 
https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/start

2) in your main.storyboard add a view controller then create a ViewController.swift file and link it to the storyboard view controller

3) Click on view controller -> go to Editor in menu -> Embed in -> navigation controller. Now you should get a navigation controller linked to your view controller.

4) Copy paste the below codings into ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit
import GooglePlaces

class ViewController: UIViewController,UISearchBarDelegate{

    var resultsViewController: GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController?
    var searchController: UISearchController?


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        resultsViewController = GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController()
        resultsViewController?.delegate = self

        searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: resultsViewController)
        searchController!.searchResultsUpdater = resultsViewController

        // Put the search bar in the navigation bar.
        searchController!.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        self.navigationItem.titleView = searchController?.searchBar

        // When UISearchController presents the results view, present it in
        // this view controller, not one further up the chain.
        self.definesPresentationContext = true

        // Prevent the navigation bar from being hidden when searching.
        searchController!.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        searchController!.searchBar.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearance.Dark
        searchController!.searchBar.barStyle = .Black

        let filter = GMSAutocompleteFilter()
        filter.country = "LK" //put your country here
        filter.type = .Establishment
        resultsViewController?.autocompleteFilter = filter


        searchController?.searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
        searchController?.searchBar.delegate = self

    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        //self.searchController?.active = true
        self.searchController!.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()

    }


    func didPresentSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
        self.searchController!.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
    }


}
// Handle the user's selection.
extension ViewController: GMSAutocompleteResultsViewControllerDelegate {
    func resultsController(resultsController: GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController,didAutocompleteWithPlace place: GMSPlace) {

        // Do something with the selected place.
        print("Pickup Place name: ", place.name)
        print("Pickup Place address: ", place.formattedAddress)
        print("Pickup Place attributions: ", place.placeID)
    }


    func resultsController(resultsController: GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController,
                           didFailAutocompleteWithError error: NSError){
        // TODO: handle the error.
        print("Error: ", error.description)
    }

    // Turn the network activity indicator on and off again.
    func didRequestAutocompletePredictionsForResultsController(resultsController: GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController) {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
    }

    func didUpdateAutocompletePredictionsForResultsController(resultsController: GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController) {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
    }


}
```

5) In your app delegate

```
import GooglePlaces

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
GMSPlacesClient.provideAPIKey(GoogleKey) //add your google key here
return true
}
```

Hope this helps to you. You can customize colors and all of this. And you can get all the details besides the primary details you getting after selecting a place in this by using the place ID of it.

You will get something like this which is totally customizable,
[image]

Comment: Thanks Bishan, I've followed these steps but I'm getting several errors: `resultsViewController?.delegate = self` gives the error **Cannot assign value of type 'SearchScreen' to type 'GMSAutocompleteResultsViewControllerDelegate?'** `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()` gives the error **'dispatch_get_main_queue()' has been replaced by property 'DispatchQueue.main'** and **'dispatch_async' has been replaced by instance method 'DispatchQueue.async(execute:)'**  `extension AutoFillViewController:` gives the error **Declaration is only valid at file scope**

Comment: Hi @AustinBerenyi sorry there was missing }. I've updated the code. Can you try again.

Comment: please see my edited comment with details about the errors I'm getting. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Yep i did few changes which will effect on your error. Just copy paste the entire code in 4th step. This should resolve errors.

Comment: I'm still getting the same errors :( I've installed GooglePlaces and pasted both sections of code in the places you indicated.

Comment: @AustinBerenyi Im extremely sorry that was my mistake. Now i tested its 100% working. Please copy paste the entire 4th step. And in app delegate give working google key.

Comment: Thank you!! It works :) I would like to add that I needed to modify the code to the following https://pastebin.com/bgn6rv5T  I was still receiving errors, but they were easily fixed. I would consider updating your answer to that code for others.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to implement google place API by providing the required keys values to fetch the near by places

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=(lat),(long)&radius=(radius)&type=(type)&hasNextPage=(true)&nextPage()=(true)&keyword=(keyword)&key=(google_services_key)&pagetoken=(pageToken)